# Outcome field in LoadTest2010's LoadTestTestResults table

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I'm running load tests in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, and I'm trying to build some custom reporting tools. In the LoadTestTestResults table, there's a column labeled Outcome. I've seen  it have the values 0, 1, 3, and (mostly) 10. But I can't find anything that explains what the different values mean.

I think that 10 is a success outcome, according to a comment in Prc_GetUserTestDetail. No clue on the others -- they don't seem to match up with any numbers in the VS summary.

What do these outcome codes mean?

Comment: It might be more useful to ask about what do you want to do instead of how to do it. Anyway, maybe this link is helpful: [Description of Tables and Columns in VS 2010 Load Test Database](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slumley/archive/2010/02/12/description-of-tables-and-columns-in-vs-2010-load-test-database.aspx)

Comment: I saw that link, but it only says this about my field:

_Outcome (tinyint): A value indicating the outcome of the test case detail_

I contacted the developer who wrote that blog, though, and he gave me the details on the field values. See the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted a Microsoft developer from the MSDN blog on VS load testing and asked about this. Here's the information I got back, in case anybody else needs it:

The Outcome field is an enum that stores the status of an individual test case within a load test run. It can have values from 0 - 13.

0 - **Error**: There was a system error while we were trying to execute a test.

1 - **Failed**: Test was executed, but there were issues. Issues may involve exceptions or failed assertions.

2 - **Timeout**: The test timed out.

3 - **Aborted**: Test was aborted. This was not caused by a user gesture, but rather by a framework decision.

4 - **Inconclusive**: Test has completed, but we can't say if it passed or failed. May be used for aborted tests...

5 - **PassedButRunAborted**: Test was executed w/o any issues, but run was aborted.

6 - **NotRunnable**: Test had its chance for been executed but was not, as ITestElement.IsRunnable == false.

7 - **NotExecuted**: Test was not executed. This was caused by a user gesture - e.g. user hit stop button.

8 - **Disconnected**: Test run was disconnected before it finished running.

9 - **Warning**: To be used by Run level results. This is not a failure.

10 - **Passed**: Test was executed w/o any issues.

11 - **Completed**: Test has completed, but there is no qualitative measure of completeness.

12 - **InProgress**: Test is currently executing.

13 - **Pending**: Test is in the execution queue, was not started yet.